# VersionOne .NET SDK Creating New Asset

Tags: c#, .net, api, sdk, versionone

I am trying to create a new Story asset through the V1 API. I am receiving an error:

**"Unhandled Exception: VersionOne.SDK.APIClient.ConnectionException: Error writing
 to output stream ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an er
ror: (400) Bad Request. ---> VersionOne.SDK.APIClient.APIException: Violation'Re
quired'AttributeDefinition'Super'Story"**

I am setting up my connector and creating the asset like so:

```
        V1Connector connector = V1Connector
            .WithInstanceUrl("xxx")
            .WithUserAgentHeader("NewApp", "1.0")
            .WithAccessToken("xxx")
            .UseOAuthEndpoints()
            .Build();

        IServices services = new Services(connector);

        Oid projectId = services.GetOid("Scope:02284");
        IAssetType storyType = services.Meta.GetAssetType("Story");
        Asset newStory = services.New(storyType, projectId);
        IAttributeDefinition nameAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Name");
        newStory.SetAttributeValue(nameAttribute, "My New Test Story");
        services.Save(newStory);
```

The error is given on the last line. I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I haven't come up with a solution. Does anybody have suggestions?

Here is a link to the example I am trying to follow: https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Get_an_SDK/.NET_SDK/Creating_Assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Violation'Required'AttributeDefinition'Super'Story** exception is being thrown because you are attempting to create a Story asset without populating the required field, **'Super'**. Someone in your organization made this a required attribute.

See your VersionOne project administrator or populate this attribute with a valid value.  In order to determine if there are other required fields, do a meta query and any attributes with the '*' next to it is required. As you can see in this png, Name and Scope are my only required attributes.

[image]

When you look at your meta data, you will see that Super is a relation to an Epic.

There are two places that you can learn about VersionOne Metadata

1) http://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Learn_the_API/Meta_API

2) http://YourVersionOneInstance/help/api

btw, a Story meta query url has a shape like this

https://YourVersionOneInstance/meta.v1/Story?xsl=api.xsl